# How can I access mongodb database connection variable in model with zend framework 3

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework

I have succeed to connect mongodb database with zend framework 3 directly without using any module. I have accessed that connection in controller by using factory. But I want to access this in every modules controllers and models i.e I want to access it globally. How can I access "$this->db" globally. Where to write the "connect" method to access that variable globally. I am new to zend framework 3 and if any one have any solution that will be very helpful to proceed with my project. I am sharing the files I have used.

**global.php**

```
 use Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage;
 use Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr;
 use Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent;

return [
    'config' => [
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 27017,
        'username'       => 'test',
        'password'       => 'test',
        'dbname'   => 'test',
        'connection_string'=> sprintf('mongodb://%s:%d/%s','127.0.0.1','27017','test')
    ],

 // Session configuration.
 'session_config' => [
        // Session cookie will expire in 1 hour.
        'cookie_lifetime' => 60*60*1,     
        // Session data will be stored on server maximum for 30 days.
        'gc_maxlifetime'     => 60*60*24*30, 
 ],
 // Session manager configuration.
 'session_manager' => [
         // Session validators (used for security).
         'validators' => [
               RemoteAddr::class,
               HttpUserAgent::class,
         ]
 ],
 // Session storage configuration.
 'session_storage' => [
         'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class
 ],
```

];

**UserControllerFactory.php**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Application\Service\AuthManager;
/**
 * This is the factory for UserController. Its purpose is to instantiate the
 * controller.
 */
class UserControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null){
        $config = $container->get('config');
        $db_config = $config['config']; 
        $authManager = $container->get(AuthManager::class);
        $authService = $container->get(\Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService::class);
        return new UserController($db_config, $authManager, $authService);
    }
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt;

class UserController extends AbstractActionController{
    private $db;
    private $authManager;
    private $authService;
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct($config, $authManager, $authService){
        $this->connect($config);
        $this->authManager = $authManager;
        $this->authService = $authService;
    }
    /**
     * Connection.
     */
    private function connect($config){
        try{
            if ( !class_exists('Mongo')){
                echo ("The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled");
                return false;
            }
            $connection=  new \MongoClient($config['connection_string'],
                    array('username'=>$config['username'],'password'=>$config['password']));
            return $this->db = $connection->selectDB($config['dbname']);
        }catch(Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to `var_dump ($connection)` to check if database connection do exist.

Comment: @Kamal I can now able to connect.But I have 1 question that is "Where to write connect function so that I can access $this->db in every controller and model?". I have updated the question. Please help if anybody have solution.